# Fill array of objects with data from multiple mysql querys

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, promise, async-await

Is there a way to pause iteration of map function so I can get response from my query and store it in some object.

So my data is an array of objects and I want to add property "receivers" for every single object in array so I use map funtion to loop through my array, problem is in callback :D ,my object reveive data after my express sends response so I had to dely response with Timeout, I know its not the right solution but it work for now because I have only 40-50 records in database.

Here is the code:

```
data.map((x) => {

      let sql = `
        SELECT username
        FROM message
        JOIN message2user ON message.message_id = message2user.message_id
        JOIN user on message2user.receiver_id = user.user_id
        where message.message_id = ?;
      `;

      testDB.query(sql, x.message_id, (err, dataReceivers) => {
        if (err) console.log(err);

        x["receivers"] = dataReceivers;
      })

    });


setTimeout(() => {
      res.json({ success: true, data: data });
}, 1000);
```

I am using express for my API routes and [MySQL](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql) module for node, maybe I sould use Promises or async functions from node, I dont know.

Do you have any ideas??

Comment: I would recommend rewriting your SQL query to just process the entire array in one query, but if you don't want to do that, I'll give you a suggestion using promises.

Comment: Hmm what do you mean entire array in one query ? i need to have array of objects (objects are some random messages) and some message can have multiple receivers, i have table that stores who receive that message but i dont know how to fill that object with array of reveivers from that table ... @PatrickRoberts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an approach using `Promises` if you don't want to refactor your SQL query:

```
const sqlTemplateString = `
SELECT username
FROM message
JOIN message2user ON message.message_id = message2user.message_id
JOIN user on message2user.receiver_id = user.user_id
where message.message_id = ?;
`;

Promise.all(data.map((x) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  testDB.query(sqlTemplateString, x.message_id, (err, dataReceivers) => {
    if (err) {
      reject(err);
    } else {
      x.receivers = dataReceivers;
      resolve(x);
    }
  });

}))).then((data) => {
  res.json({
    success: true,
    data
  });
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);

  res.json({
    success: false,
    error
  });
});
```

Or something like that.

Comment: Thank you dude, that is exactly what i needed, thanks!!
Guess i still have a lot to learn about promises :D